# "fall down to", "fall down in" or "fall down into"? How to emphasis?

Tags: word-usage, emphasis

I want to talk about a man. He thinks too much and can't get out of his mind. And I want to say that "he fell down [...] the pit in his head himself."  Which should I say?

> And he fell down **to** the pit in his head himself.

or

> And he fell down **into** the pit in his head himself.

or

> And he fell down **in** the pit in his head himself.

Can I use **himself** to emphasize **the pit**? If not, show me a way else, please.

Comment: Neither sentence makes sense. I suppose that, figuratively, people might have pits in their heads—but more context would be required to understand its use here. The use of the reflexive *himself* is even more confusing. Without using a sentence that makes sense, it's not really possible to say which preposition should be used. Although part of me wants to say you should use **into** just to simplify the matter . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford I want to talk about a man. He thinks too much and can't get out of his mind. And I want to say that "he fell down [...] the pit in his head himself." I have one more question. Can I use "himself" to 
emphasize "the pit"? If not, show me a way else, please.

Comment: You should always include those kinds of details in your posts. Otherwise, they may be closed as "unclear" or "lacking details". You can [edit] your post any time to improve it. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785#4785) for more tips and examples.

Comment: What do you mean by *emphasize the pit*? (The reflexive isn't used as an intensifier in that way.) Do you mean that others have done the same thing and that now he's doing it too?

Comment: Thanks, but please consider [waiting longer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *fall **into*** a pit, or you can *fall **down*** a pit, which roughly mean he entered a pit by falling (what I think you intend). *Fall down **into*** also seems possible to me, if you take it to be the phrasal verb *fall down* with *into*. This also means he fell and entered a pit.  To me, he *fell **in** a pit* could mean that; it could also mean he was standing in a pit and then fell. "Himself" is does not modify "pit". "Himself" could be used to emphasize that he too fell into a pit, or possibly to clarify that he fell in as opposed to someone or something else. Otherwise, it doesn't seem necessary.

Your usage of a figurative pit might be understood, but there is a similar, idiomatic phrase in English:

> [rabbit hole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabbit%20hole) noun
>   Definition of rabbit hole
>
> : a complexly bizarre or difficult state or situation conceived of as a hole into which one falls or descends
>   *I wanted to show this woman descending into the rabbit hole: this loss of self, becoming a servant to her job and to the work.*
>   — Jessica Chastain
>
> especially : one in which the pursuit of something (such as an answer or solution) leads to other questions, problems, or pursuits
>   *While trying to find the picture again on Google, I fell down the Cosmo rabbit hole, scrolling through a gallery of swimwear, then through "How to Be Sexier-Instantly" and then through all 23 slides of "Sexy Ideas for Long Hair."*
>   — Edith Zimmerman
>
> (M-W)

Then your example becomes

> And he fell down the *rabbit hole* in his mind.

You could also consider *got lost in his thoughts*:

> [lost in thought](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+in+thought)
>   Fully and deeply engrossed in a thought or idea, often to such a degree as to be unaware of or insensitive to the outside world. *It's no use trying to talk to Helen when she's lost in thought like that; it's as if we don't even exist!*
>   (TFD)